# tableView:indexPathForCell returns nil when clicking in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I know indexPath will return nil when the cell is hidden, but my question is why it is not visible?

My case is that:
There is a button in the cell when button is clicked, and it tries to get the indexPath( by selector indexPathForCell: )

Meanwhile the tableview is refreshed by another thread.

Sometimes the indexPath will get nil, my question is because the button is in the cell, when event was fired the cell must exist ( otherwise how should the button be clicked ), what happened causing the cell hidden?

thx.

---

```
//Cell.m
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIButton   *button;
@property (nonatomic, weak) XXXDelegate   *delegate;

-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    UIButton * button = xxx;
    [self.contentView addSubview:button];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(xxxClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)xxxClick:(id)sender{
   [self.delegate xxxClick:self];
}

//Controller.m
-(void)loadView{
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"xxx"];
}    

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {      
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"xxx" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //update cell
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}

- (void)xxxClick:(UITableViewCell*) cell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    //indexPath is nil sometimes? why?
}
```

And also, the tableview reloads sometimes

Comment: Your question is confusing. Could you provide more code?

Comment: why self is cell here, you should be adding target over the viewcontroller

Comment: add some example code, thx

Comment: Your cell doesn't call `[super initWithStyle:]`. `loadView` does not put anything into `self.view`. All such things can create many many problems.

Comment: I called [super initWithStyle:] and the code above is just example and it runs normally most of time

Answer (score 2):

Thx guys,I finally got the answer.

When the button is triggered and the tableview is "reloadData" in the same runloop, "reloadData" cause the cell to be invisible, and "indexPathForCell" will get nil.

It is dangerous if you do not check the value of indexPath.

Comment: Weird but true! `indexPathForCell ` will always be `nil` if there is previously issued `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` in the same run loop iteration. It is somewhat obvious though, since starting from iOS10 any reload message to table view is actually deferred until the next layout pass, running on a different run loop iteration. One way I found to overcome this is to enclose reload commands inside a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...` block. It just works somehow!

Answer (score 1):

Might you can have wrong reuse identifier which is defined in the custom cell in the storyboard.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : SingleLabelTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SingleLabelTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SingleLabelTableCell
    let tempDict : NSDictionary = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
    cell.nameLabel.text = tempDict.valueForKey("title") as? String
    return cell
}
```

or You can check it on this video tutorial link also

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHue6nFUBO8

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use in below format

**Cell.h**

```
//
//   Cell.h
//   Projects


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Cell : UITableViewCell


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnCall;

@end
```

**Cell.m**

```
//
//  Cell.m


#import "Cell.h"


@implementation NearByDealDetailCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];


}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

**// ControllerVC.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
        Cell *cell = (Cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }


               cell.btnCall.tag =  indexPath.row;
        [cell.btnCall addTarget:self action:@selector(actionBtnCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return cell;

}



- (IBAction)actionBtnCall:(id)sender {

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NearByDealModel *activity = (NearByDealModel *)[self.activityList objectAtIndex:[btn tag]];

}
```